# Reuse Array of Char Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Suppose I want to "reuse" an array of char pointers, like in the following program that loops files given in the argument list, loops the lines in the file, adds them to a dynamically allocated array, then prints it:

```
// includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// globals
int progReturn = 0;
int globalLineCounter = 0;



////// main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int i;


    // iterate files. first arg is the program name
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "The file '%s' did not exist.\n", argv[i]); 
            progReturn = 1;

        } else {

            // read lines from the file
            char line[256];

            // THE PROBLEM: I'd like to completely clear this array.            
            char **lines = malloc(16 * sizeof(char*));

            // iterate lines
            int fileLineCounter = 0;
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {

                // remove newline
                strtok(line, "\n"); 

                // add lines to array
                lines[globalLineCounter] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(lines[globalLineCounter], line);
                //printf("%s\n", lines[globalLineCounter]); // tester

                fileLineCounter++;
                globalLineCounter++;                
            }
            // all lines read
            printf("The file '%s' had %d lines.\n", argv[i], fileLineCounter);

            // print the array
            int j=0;
            for (j=0; j<fileLineCounter; j++) {
                // PROBLEM: Garbage from the second file when it prints here. 
                printf("%s\n", lines[j]);
            }

            // delete lines, delete file
            memset(lines, 0, sizeof(*lines));
            fclose(fp);
        }  
    }
    // all files read

    return progReturn;
}
```

On the first file, everything works with no problems. On the second file, when I print the array, It shows unprintable characters, and some of the lines from the first file.

What could be causing this issue? Am I not fully clearing `**lines`?

---

EDIT: example input and output:

input file foo:

```
This is a test
of the lineSort program
in order to
test its capabilities.
Lots of whitespace too!
aaa

bbb

         cccccc



aaa
ggggg
hhhhh
fffff
eeeee
ddddd
ppppp
```

input file bar:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
ccccccccccccccccc
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

output for `sortLine foo bar`:

```
The file 'foo' had 20 lines.





         cccccc
Lots of whitespace too!
This is a test
aaa
aaa
bbb
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
in order to
of the lineSort program
ppppp
test its capabilities.
The file 'bar' had 5 lines.
(x▒▒
(x▒▒
Lots of whitespace too!
in order to
test its capabilities.
```

Comment: You're not reusing anything there.

Comment: Unrelated nitpick: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, so multiplying by it is unnecessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is `fileLineCounter`? It isn't defined anywhere. Compile with `gcc -Wall` and let us know what you see.

Comment: @melpomene - could you elaborate? The goal is to not reuse the previous array from the last file, but start with a brand new array. Also, I addressed for mcve by adding the main function.

Comment: And what is `buf` used for?

Comment: There are memory management issues with your code. Start with reviewing `malloc` and `free`. Every `malloc` that you do to set up a pointer has to have a `free` somewhere at the end of that pointer's life. If you do a `malloc` twice without a corresponding `free`, you get a memory leak and I'll bet that your problems come from that.

Comment: @AlexReynolds No, memory leaks don't make other code misbehave. They just waste space.

Comment: @melpomene - I've removed the functionality from functions.h, as its not related to the problem, in interest of a minimal example. I am aware header files do not define functions - I have a functions.c as well.

Comment: How are you running this program? What's in the input files?

Comment: @AlexReynolds - Doesn't the `memset` call completely clear the `**lines` allocations?

Comment: `lines` is an array of pointers, `memset` clears those pointers (to all bits zero), the memory pointed to by those pointers is not cleared and may well be returned again by the next `malloc` call (if you were to `free` it first). In any case the `memset` is pointless - if you want to free the memory, use `free`, if you want to ensure the memory is zeroed before you use it (not needed for your use here), `memset` after `malloc` (or use `calloc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    strcpy(lines[globalLineCounter], line);
```

This looks like your main problem. `globalLineCounter` keeps increasing across all input files.

Let's say your first input file contains 10 lines and your second file 5 lines. Then your code will create a dynamic array (of dynamic arrays) and store the lines from the first file in elements `0` .. `9` (and then print them). You never free any of the allocated memory, so it all leaks at the end of the loop.

For the second file, you create another dynamic array. You store the 5 lines from the second file in elements `10` .. `14` (via `globalLineCounter`), but then print elements `0` .. `4` (`fileLineCounter`). Those elements are uninitialized and contain garbage.

Comment: All I can say is... Doh! That fixed it up. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the `char **lines` initialization outside of the `for` loop.
2. Rename the index counter `i` to something different.
3. Repeatedly calling `lines[i] = malloc(...)` on multiple files will cause a memory leak. Think about using `free` inside the `for` loop, or move this part of the initialization outside the `for` loop.

Comment: That doesn't really address the question.

Comment: This might or might not be worth taking to chat. I can't really fit what I want to say in this comment field.